# External Libraries in Programming

Tags: c++, fortran, netcdf

This is a newb question. I'm not sure if "external libraries" is the right terminology, but I see some programs `include` or `use` libraries or modules that are not programmer-defined. Do I need to do anything special when compiling - do I need to tell the compiler where to find these external libraries?

For example, on this page http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/, SimpleXyWr.cpp and simple_xy_wr.f90 both reference the netCDF library/module. How does the compiler know where to find the library/module? Do I need to provide the path myself at some point in the compilation?

Comment: What compiler package are you using? Generally, there's a specific order in which the compiler tools will search to find your libraries, but you can tell most compilers where to find these libraries, and yes, you do need to specify if it's not on the default search path (current working directory, system library location, LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (unix/linux, PATH on Windows), etc.)

Comment: I'm using GNU - gfortran for Fortran. How would I go about telling gfortran where netCDF modules are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for GNU compilers -L options tells where to find library and -l tells what library to link. For example,

```
f77 -o run main.f -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas
```

will look for libraries in `/usr/local/lib` driectory and link with `lapack` and `blas` libraries